# Entity Framework 6 pegar atributos no SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou utilizando o `Entity Framework 6` com `Oracle`. A base de dados é de um sistema legado, eu pretendo setar na mão as chaves primárias dos registros.

Para facilitar a vida, quero pegar no `SaveChanges` do `DbContext` os dados da tabela e os campos que são chave primária para executar o comando SQL abaixo, assim evitando conflitos.

### Dúvida

No meu `DbContext`, como faço para pegar os atributos `Table` e `Key` e seus respectivos valores?

#### SQL

```
public int GetNextID(string field, string table)
{
    return Database.SqlQuery<int>("select coalesce(max(" + field + "), 0) + 1 from " + table).First();
}
```

#### Classe

```
[Table("CHAMADOS")]
public class Chamado
{
    [Key]
    [Column("CD_CODIGO")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    [Obrigatorio]
    [Column("CD_EM_CODIGO")]
    public int Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

#### Meu DbContext

```
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public OracleDbContext()
        : base("OracleDbContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OracleDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");
    }    

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var registro in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (registro.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                // Gostaria de pegar aqui os dados do atributo Table e Key da classe
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public DbSet<Chamado> Chamado { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: não há necessidade de você pegar o id da sua tabela antes de salvar, a não ser que seja para fazer um update. claro se você usar o IDENTITY do banco de dados.

Comment: Primeiramente cuidado com essa abordagem de selecionar o max, isso seria um problema caso voce tenha uma chave composta e também você estará realizando uma leitura na sua tabela sempre que inserir na mesma, é uma abordagem perigosa.

Verifiquei também que voce está utilizando Oracle, já tentou utilizar sequence com trigger? Não funcionou como esperado?

Comment: Seguindo a dica do @NícolasTarzia, com você usa Oracle, porque não usar [Sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm)?